# clicking on dynamically added element does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that when pressed adds another div with the same class. But when I click on the dynamically added elements, nothing happens.

```js
$('.container').on('click', function(){
  var newColumn = $('<li class="column"/>');
  var newState = $('<div class="container" unselectable="on">Nothing</div>');
  newState.appendTo(newColumn);
  newColumn.appendTo($('#canvas'));
});
```

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:40px;
  border-radius:10px;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
}

.column{
  list-style-type: none;
  display:inline;
  width:100px;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="canvas">
  <li class="column">
    <div class="container" unselectable="on">
      works
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I make the click-event work for all the elements?

Comment: Use a delegated event: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `.container` elements are created automatically by your script you have to use the event delegation **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to deal with fresh DOM :

```
$('body').on('click', '.container', function(){
     //Your code here
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(document).on('click', '.container', function(){
  var newColumn = $('<li class="column"/>');
  var newState = $('<div class="container" unselectable="on">Nothing</div>');
  newState.appendTo(newColumn);
  newColumn.appendTo($('#canvas'));
});
```

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:40px;
  border-radius:10px;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
}

.column{
  list-style-type: none;
  display:inline;
  width:100px;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="canvas">
  <li class="column">
    <div class="container" unselectable="on">
      works
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```